# Cache FIDO2 security PIN for a few hours

Tags: windows-11, pin, fido2

How to configure Windows to remember my Security Key PIN for a few hours? I've just checked: logged in to the same site twice in incognito mode within 1 minute and I was asked for the PIN twice.

[image]
_

Comment: Does it happen outside of incognito mode?

Comment: The purpose of incognito mode is to not remember credentials ...